# Do all threads originating from the same process sleep on wait_event_interruptible()?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, pthreads

If I have 3 pthreads: A, B, C, all originating from the same process, running in user space and one thread, thread B does a blocking read from a kernel module and is put to sleep, will threads A and C also be put to sleep as a result?

According to the documentation, [wait_event_interruptible](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-internals/device-drivers/API-wait-event-interruptible.html) puts the calling process to sleep, not thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing personally, it appears only the calling thread is put to sleep, not any other threads. While one thread was waiting during a blocked read, the other threads were still active.

Comment: In Linux, threads are implemented as very light weight processes, so the documentation is technically correct.